# Why does my code not work with a player object?

Tags: javascript

I added a player object for save games to my "game" (aka me learning JS), but it seems that the game is not working anymore because of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/TieSoul/Jjmdv/10/

```
player = {}
```

and all related things seem to make it non-functional even though it should still work afaik.

Comment: Please post your code here. Just linking to jsfiddle won't do.

Answer (score 0):

You have some other issues too in your code but.. add this:

```
player.player = {};
```

Like:

```
var player = {};
player.cookies = 0;
player.cookieIncrement = 1;
player.buildingsArr = [0];
player.player = {}; //HERE
player.player.buildingsCost = [10];
player.player.buildingsForEvery = [1];
player.buildingsName = ['Cursors'];
player.cursUpgrGet = [0, 0];
player.cursUpgrCost = [50, 200];
player.upgradeAmnt = [2];
player.fps = 60;
player.cps = 0;
```

Also try using some javascript consoles while coding like firebug.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are quite a few errors, I am not sure what you want to fix.

I replaced, in the html part of the jsfiddle:

```
var e = document.getElementById("player.cookies");
```

by:

```
var e = document.getElementById("cookies");
```

Basically you have a **document.getElementById('player.cookies')** but you can not find it because the element with id **player.cookies** doesnt exist.

And you can see the cookies made.

Basically you tried to modify the innerHTML of a non existing element (player.cookies).

I also changed:

```
player.player.buildingsCost = [10];
player.player.buildingsForEvery = [1];
```

by:

```
player.buildingsCost = [10];
player.buildingsForEvery = [1];
```

The jsfiddle with my changes to your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jjmdv/14/

Note that now there is a counter for the cookies.

Comment: Whoops, I replaced the things with player.(word) when I made the player object, and I thought I had got rid of all the odd things :S